# How to load two different views in same file using one function in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have view which has form for selecting search parameters such as search by category, I am loading that with function name `search_by_category()`. This function gets categories and pass it to the view so view can populate all the categories in drop down. This form will go to a new function for submission and that function will get record as per category, but I will lose the search form in that new function, how can I have two together in one view.

**CODE:**

```
public function select_by_category()
{
   $a = getcategories();
   return view('show_categories_and_form', $a);
}

public function get_form_record(Request $request)
{
   $a = $request->input('category_id');
   $b = get_record_as_per_category($a);

   return view('show_categories_and_form', $b);
}
```

If I load `view('show_categories_and_form', $b)` it will not show categories or do I have to get categories again in this function ?

```
   @include('header_file')


  <form method="post" action="{{ URL::to('/get_form_record') }}">
    <!-- <div class="form-group">             
          <label for="name">Search By Link:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="link"/>
      </div> -->
      <div class="form-group">
      @csrf
          <label for="price">Search By Category:</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="category">
          <option value="">Select Category</option>
          @foreach($getCategories as $getcats)
          <option value="{{$getcats->id}}">{{$getcats->category_name}} </option>
          @endforeach
          </select>
      </div>         

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
  </form>
```

```
        @include('footer_file')
```

Comment: Show us some code so we can better help you :)

Comment: I have updated the question please reply

Comment: Show us the `show_categories_and_form` blade as well.

Comment: :) are you there

Comment: Where do you want to use get_record_as_per_category's data in your view?

Comment: in the same view by adding table cells or rows, I didn't put that code to avoid complexity

Answer (score 0):

try to check $b first. try to return it to see the result.

if it is empty then the mistake is from get_record_as_per_category();

if it is not empty then the mistake is form the result of $b.
i assume that $a contain objects, meanwhile $b contain array.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this how you want it.

You can reload the whole form, which would mean reloading the categories every time, along with the `get_record_as_per_category()` in the same function.  This would give it to you in one view, and is the simplest concept.

You can also load every record (all categories) and send to the page *from the start*, along with all the categories like you already are in your example code above.  Then, when a user changes the category, you can use JavaScript/jQuery to hide all the incorrect records and show only the correct records for the category chosen.

I think the closest approach to what you want would be to have one more 'include' file (like you did with your header & footer).  So, the top part would stay the same as you have it now - the same form.  Then, between your category form and the footer, include this new part... let's call it chosen_records.  When the user changes categories, you only need to reload the chosen_records part of the form via an ajax call.

This would be like so:

```
@include('header_file')

<form method="post" action="{{ URL::to('/get_form_record') }}">
    //  Your code as above
</form>

<div id=chosen_guts>
   @include('chosen_records')
</div>

@include('footer_file')

<script>
  //pseudo code
  ajax{
    call to get_form_record();
    success(successHtml):
      $("#chosen_guts").html(successHtml); 
  }
</script>
```

Then, because you've created a view JUST for the chosen records, you can easily grab just this view with the correct records to return to the ajax call:

```
public function get_form_record(Request $request)
{
   $a = $request->input('category_id');
   $b = get_record_as_per_category($a);

   // for the ajax call, we just return the guts, not the form
   return view('chosen_records', $b);
}
```

For the very first view, from the first time you display the page, you need to decide if you want to include a set of records for a 'default' category to display in the chosen_records section.  If so, in the initial function, `select_by_category()`, you'll need to include the call to get those records:

```
$b = get_record_as_per_category($someDefaultCategory);
```

Lots of choices, depending on what you are comfortable with.

HTH

Comment: I was looking for something like $this->load->view('head'); $this->load->view('content'); $this->load->view('foot');  like we do in codeigniter

Comment: that was simple isn't it. Is there anyway like that

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what the get_form_record() function above is doing.  It is only loading the partial view for the chosen records.  *Something* has to call the controller after the category choice though, so you have a choice of doing it all at once without ajax (first option I showed), or preferably to load only the content via an ajax call.  The answer above is exactly what you are asking for, I believe.